ASP.NET Core versioning, UrlSegmentApiVersionReader, routes match nonsense version numbers
I am using the ASP versioning library to version an ASP.NET Core Web API controller in a micro service.
using Asp.Versioning;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;

[ApiController]
[ApiVersion("1")]
[ControllerName("example")]
[Route("v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]

In this controller, I have defined a few actions, e.g. one to get the version:
[HttpGet("version")]
[Produces("text/plain")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public IActionResult GetVersion() => ...

If I perform a curl GET operation with any version number, I get the matched route for version. In some ways this is not surprising, because I am using version neutral matching for the action. However, given that the controller route has an [ApiVersion] of 1 only, I expected any other non-declared version number to result in a 404 not found.
curl -X GET http://localhost:8127/v1/system/version
0.0.0.0%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
curl -X GET http://localhost:8127/v1337/system/version
0.0.0.0% 

Have I mis-configured this? Is it possible to have non-declared versions rejected rather than matched? With UrlSegmentApiVersionReader the default (and assume by default) is not specified for my code, as all versions have be explicitly provided for URL versions.
services.AddApiVersioning(opt =>
{
    opt.ApiVersionReader = new UrlSegmentApiVersionReader();
}).AddApiExplorer(opt =>
{
    opt.GroupNameFormat = "'v'V";
});

I have followed the example provided here under "ASP.NET Core with MVC (Core)".

Hi @Syntax, so you means if you use other undeclared version, it will also give the response instead of 404? What is your targerframework version? How do you configure the api version in Startup or Program?

Hi @Rena, Thank you for your input/ideas. I have updated the ticket with more information, hopefully this helps you and others!

HI @Syntax, Could you pls share your project file?  Or even it is better for you to share a minimal repo which could reproduce your issue. By testing your shared code, it works fine.

When you say it works fine, do you mean that your receive a 404 NotFound on a request with a version number that isn't version 1?

Hi @Syntax,Ok I got it. You do not want to get the 400 with error message like: The HTTP resource that matches the request URI 'https://localhost:5001/v3/WeatherForecast/version' does not support the API version '3'.. Only want to get the 404 not found.

If you use the framework before .net 6, it seems to be impossible. If you use .net 6 or beyond .net 6, you can set options.UnsupportedApiVersionStatusCode = 404;. Besides, it should be [ApiVersion(1.0)].  Use [ApiVersion("1") cannot work fine.

Sorry for the slow response, as shown above, when I query nonsense versions I get 200 (as shown in curl results above). I would be happy to receive a 400, it is the 200 status code responses which motivated me to post this question TBH

What should happen if an API version doesn't match has long been a gray area. No scenario highlights it more than when versioning by URL segment. It's just one of the many issues with using that method of versioning (as well as not being RESTful).
The existing behavior is to return 400. Starting in API Versioning 6.0, there are changes to the routing extensions that will lead to 404 when versioning by URL segment in some cases - but not all. In the cases that are not 404, the response is still 400. This is primarily to retain backward compatibility. If you want to return 404 instead, there is a simple escape hatch. You just need set the option:
builder.Services
       .AddApiVersioning(options =>
        {
            options.ApiVersionReader = new UrlSegmentApiVersionReader();
            options.UnsupportedApiVersionStatusCode = 404;
        })
       .AddMvc()
       .AddApiExplorer(options => options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'V");

This will still produce ProblemDetails if they are configured, but the status code will be 404 instead of 400.

If I read the above correctly, then without specifying UnsupportedApiVersionStatusCode, shouldn't I expect to receive a 400 then instead of a 200 for version 1337?

I suspect my use of EnableEndpointRouting = false and app.UseMvc() are responsible for my problems (I have removed both now). I will continue digging into this, but your example above may have put me on the right path! Currently I'm getting 404 for all calls, but I can see the routes are registered with the IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.

Once I replaced app.UseMvc() with app.UseRouting(), app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers()) and also updated my AddMvc call to use the all on the IApiVersioningBuilder (as per your example) versus the service collection's AddMvc() then I was able to get the expected behaviour.

@Syntax yes, IApiVersioningBuilder.AddMvc is different and does something different than IMvcServiceExtensions.AddMvc. The legacy IRouteBuilder is still supported, but I would not recommend it. There are some edge cases where things may not work as you expect. The guidance since ASP.NET 2.2  has been to use Endpoint Routing. The full explanation is a bit lengthy, but it looks like you have changed things up and go it working.

Shorten Answer
If you want to return the invalid version response with 404 Not Found, it seems to be impossible before .NET 6. You can achieve it by using @Chris Martinez do by setting options.UnsupportedApiVersionStatusCode = 404;. You need install the package Asp.Versioning.Mvc.ApiExplorer instead of old version Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer by using or beyond
.NET 6.
Besides, please note it should be [ApiVersion(1.0)] instead of [ApiVersion("1").
Explanation For Why Cannot Set Status Code To 404 Before .NET 6
You can custom the error response by custom the IErrorResponseProvider and set the provider to options.ErrorResponses. For how to custom the provider should be like below:
public class CustomErrorResponseProvider : DefaultErrorResponseProvider
{
    public override IActionResult CreateResponse(ErrorResponseContext context)
    {
        if (context.ErrorCode == "UnsupportedApiVersion")
        {
            context.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        }

        return base.CreateResponse(context);
    }
}

Then you can see the StatusCode is readonly, that is to say you cannot change the status code. Check the source code below:
    public partial class ErrorResponseContext
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the associated HTTP status code.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The associated HTTP status code.</value>
#if WEBAPI
        public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; }
#else
        public int StatusCode { get; }
#endif

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the associated error code.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The associated error code.</value>
        public string ErrorCode { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the associated error message.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The error message.</value>
        public string Message { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the detailed error message.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The detailed error message, if any.</value>
        public string? MessageDetail { get; }
    }


This is a very, very old version of API Versioning. IErrorResponseProvider and DefaultErrorResponseProvider do not even exist anymore. A similar approach can be achieved using the IProblemDetailsWriter. Backward compatibility is available to transform Problem Details into the old Error Object format.

Hi @Chris Martinez, Yes. But you can see that op use services.xxxx. It seems the targetframework is before .NET 6 which will not use the new package Asp.Versioning.Mvc.ApiExplorer. The new package is used beyond .NET 6 and the service registion beyond .NET 6 will be builder.Services.xxx.

Notes for posterity; I'm using .Net 8, I have Asp.Versioning.Mvc.ApiExplorer v 8.1.0 as the dependency. UnsupportedApiVersionStatusCode looks like exactly what I would need if I wanted to convert 400 to 404 (which I'm less concerned about truthfully). My bigger concern, is that GET for unsupported versions yields a status code 200 response. r.e. the Version attribute, both appear to be available (double and string), I prefer the use of the string because I personally don't want a version 1.0 and I'm happy to increment versions as whole numbers.

As it turns out using [Version(1.0)] is fine and maps correctly when the configuration problems were fixed, thank you for the suggestion and feedback!

@Rena before 6.0 (~2.5 years ago), this was the way to set/change the HTTP status code for API Versioning errors. You can't really tell which package is being used from just services as you could simply have captured the value with var services = builder.Services; first. Since all of the older packages have been deprecated, I typically don't expect new questions to be related to them, but they could have been. The giveaways for me were using Asp.Versioning; and .AddApiVersioning().AddApiExplorer(), which indicates the IApiVerisoningBuilder in 6.0+

To add merit to this answer, if you're using the - now deprecated - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.* packages, this answer is the correct way to transform the error response.
